# How do crossbred dragons inherit movement, MR, and special defenses?

Tags: adnd-2e, dragons, monster-design

1990's *Draconomicon* has some guidelines for crossbred dragons that seem useful for 3.5/5e. From what I can tell, though, rules for land/flight/(swim) speeds, magic resistance, and elemental immunity (which I've seen implied to be tied to breath type, but it's easier to find exceptions than a confirmation on this, so maybe it counts as an "innate ability"?) seem to be absent from its guidelines.

What determines what those values should be?

Answer (score 1):

The best determinant is "what kind of foe will challenge the players and engage them" so you need to think about how the cross-breed will fit into your campaign.  You decide what percentage of each of the parent's key traits is in the offspring.  Or you can roll dice and randomly assign percentages.

Create a list of the special attributes that matter to you in each parent then assign (or randomize) the percentages/adjustments to each.  You will basically be simulating mother nature and creating some unique children.  I used to do this with demons or any monsters when my players knew exactly how to defeat the standard versions (and with demons, you get to combine 3 parents because...well... they're demons and that's how they roll lol).